# Is it possible to instantiate a class and assign it to a member variable in a single statement in Java?

Tags: java, class

I'm looking to do something like this in Java:

```
public OuterClass {

    public innerClass = new Object() {
        private var1;

        public void myMethod() {
           ...
        }
    }

}
```

and use it like this:

```
OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
outer.innerClass.myMethod();
```

The reason is to basiclly namespace some methods within the OuterClass to keep things organised.

I know I could create an instance of innerClass and assign it to a public instance variable of OuterClass but I'm looking for an inline way of doing it like above example. I don't want it to be possible to instantiate the innerClass more than once hence the inline approach.

This woule be similar to the following JavaScript:

```
var innerObject = new function() {
   ...       
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the `Singleton` design pattern?

Comment: No. Though the inner class needs to access member variables of the outclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you asked in the question title is possible, but unfortunately not what you really want.

In your code, the line with the declaration of the field `innerClass` misses a type for the field. With the rest of the code unchanged, there is only one possibility: `Object`.

So your code would read like this:

```
public OuterClass {

    public Object innerClass = new Object() {
        private var1;

        public void myMethod() {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is actually possible, but calling the method `myMethod` is not possible. When you access `outer.innerClass`, this expression is of type `Object`, which does not have a method `myMethod`, so the code won't compile.

You can however introduce an interface `MyInnerInterface`

```
interface MyInnerInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

and change the type of the field to `MyInnerInterface`:

```
public OuterClass {

    public MyInnerInterface innerClass = new MyInnerInterface() {
        private var1;

        public void myMethod() {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then accessing the method is possible. However you have the drawback of the additional interface.

Also this code is unusual and I wouldn't consider it good. If you really want to have an inner class here, don't use an anonymous class, but a real class:

```
public OuterClass {

    public class InnerClass  {
        private var1;

        public void myMethod() {
           ...
        }
    }

    public InnerClass innerClass = new InnerClass();
}
```

Still, using an inner class for "scoping" accesses from the outside is something I wouldn't do. Inner classes should usually be an implementing detail of the outer class and not be accessible to the public. Better think about how to separate your API into real co-existing classes (which of course might have references onto each other, and possibly access package-private members).

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass o = new OuterClass();
        o.new InnerClass().method();
    }

    class InnerClass {

        public void method() {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

That uses the syntax you propose, but does not address your requirement that you don't want more than one instance of InnerClass.